# initializing a typedef struct pointer to NULL

Tags: pointers, struct, initialization, typedef

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct student{
int id;
int mark;
}stud;

typedef struct stud *s1;

void main(){
s1 = NULL;
printf("hi");
}
```

Please help me how to initialize struct pointer to NULL. i get the following error during compilation.

```
graph.c: In function ‘main’:  
graph.c:11:04: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to define the variable `s1` as

```
stud *s1;
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/9ThCDi

The reason you got the error you did is that you were declaring `s1` to be a type for "pointer to struct stud".  This is wrong for two reasons:

1. You didn't want `s1` to be a type; you wanted it to be an object.
2. Your struct was `struct student`.  But you defined an actual type called `stud`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **struct student *s1;**

instead of

typedef struct stud *s1;

as far as i know, typedef is used when you are defining your custom data type only.